# What does the exclamation mark on a timestamp mean?

Tags: support, users

I've noticed a couple of times that in comments (where I've seen it, but maybe it's in questions/answers as well) that sometimes the stamp is
 -- UserName X [time unit(s)] ago *!*

Where most other comments are 
 -- UserName X [time unit(s)] ago

What's the exclamation point mean?

Comment: Does it look like this?

Comment: @C.Ross Yes it does!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you're probably [referring to the edit indicator](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/245251#245251), which looks like a pencil.  If you hover over it it will say `this comment was edited`.  If it's been edited multiple times it will also state that.